# Using CACornerMask with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, calayer, ios11

With iOS 11 we now have `CACornerMask` and the `maskedCorners` property on `CALayers`. However I am unable to set multiple corners to be rounded at the same time in Objective-C.

The swift implementation is:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
view.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
```

But in Objective-C this does not work:

```
view.layer.maskedCorners = @[kCALayerMinXMinYCorner, kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner];
```

I think this is because Swift is using an `OptionSetType` but I don't know what the Objective-C equivalent to that is.

Has anyone been able to successfully use multiple masked corners with Objective-C? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Objective-C you need to use bitwise OR (`|`) to combine the values:

```
view.layer.maskedCorners = kCALayerMinXMinYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner;
```